Show that $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi |\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{d\to \infty} \sqrt{d}\cos(m!x)^{2d}|dx=0 $.
Let $((-\pi,\pi], \mathcal{B}((-\pi,\pi]), \mu)$ be a measure space with Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Show that for $m, d\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left|\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{d\to \infty} \sqrt{d}\cos(m!x)^{2d}\right|dx=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{d\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left| \sqrt{d}\cos(m!x)^{2d}\right|dx=1/\sqrt{\pi}
$$

It seems that we can use this result: Show that $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n[\cos (x+k)]^d\to (d-1)!!/d!! \mbox{ for $d$ is even } $

for $m$-a.e. all $x\in (-\pi, \pi]$ that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n[\cos (x+k)]^d\to (d-1)!!/d!!\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{d\pi}} \mbox{ for $d$ is even }
$$
otherwise it is $0$, as $n\to \infty$.


Fix notation.  First, $m$ is Lebesgue measure, but then $m \to \infty$?  When you write $m!$ do you implicitly assume $m$ is an integer?  What about $d$, must it be integer?

@GEdgar Fix it.

By $\cos(m!x)^{2d}$ do you mean $(\cos(m!x))^{2d}$ or $\cos ((m!x)^{2d})$?

@AlexRavsky I mean the later one. Because we need to apply that Lemma.

For the first one, for a fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and for any $x \neq \frac{k\pi}{m!}$, $|\cos{(m!x)}|<1$, so
$$
\lim_{d \to \infty} \sqrt{d} \left(\cos{(m!x)}\right)^{2d} = 0
$$
so if you take $m$ to infinity avoiding those points the limit is always zero, since the set
$$
\left\{x \in [-\pi,\pi] \colon x=\frac{k\pi}{m!} \ \text{for some} \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{and} \ m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
is countable, the function that you are integrating is zero a.e.
Now, for the second equality, we use that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\cos{x}\right)^{2n} dx = 2\pi\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}
$$
notice that, by the formula above and Stirling Formula:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{d} \left(\cos{(m!x)}\right)^{2d}| dx &= \sqrt{d}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\cos{(m!x)}\right)^{2d} dx = \frac{\sqrt{d}}{m!}\int_{-m!\pi}^{m!\pi} \left(\cos{x}\right)^{2d} dx \\ 
&= \frac{\sqrt{d}}{m!}m!\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\cos{x}\right)^{2d} dx = \sqrt{d}\frac{2\pi(2d)!}{(2^d d!)^2} \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{d}\pi}{2^{2d}}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2d)}((2d)e^{-1})^{2d}(1+O(d^{-1}))}{(\sqrt{2\pi d}(de^{-1})^{d}(1+O(d^{-1})))^2} \\
&= 2\sqrt{\pi}\frac{1+O(d^{-1})}{(1+O(d^{-1}))^2} = 2\sqrt{\pi} + o(1)
\end{align*}
hence
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{d \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sqrt{d} \left(\cos{(m!x)}\right)^{2d}| dx = \lim_{m \to \infty} 2\sqrt{\pi} = 2\sqrt{\pi}.
$$
Maybe I made some mistake in my computation because the result in the end was different but I think this idea should work.

I noticed that if instead of computing the integral we compute the average (so divide it by $2\pi$) the final result would be the same, so maybe this is what you want?

Too long for a comment.
I think that something is wrong in the question. Indeed, let $\|t||$ denote the distance from the real number $t$ to the nearest integer. Suppose that for a real $\alpha>$ there exists the finite limit $\lim_{d\to \infty} \sqrt{d}\cos \alpha^d$. It follows that the set $\{\sqrt{d} \|\frac 2{\pi}\alpha^d\|:d\in\mathbb N\}$ is bounded (in particular, $\lim_{d\to \infty} \|\frac 2{\pi}\alpha^d\|=0$). The former condition is very close to that required in Pisot's theorem and the latter fits to Pisot–Vijayaraghavan problem, see here.
Therefore, since the number $\frac 2{\pi}$ is transcendental, no such number $\alpha$ is known and it is highly improbable that it exists. At least, by Pisot's theorem, $\alpha$ cannot be algebraic. So if $(m!x)^2>1$ is algebraic, then the limit $\lim_{d\to \infty} \sqrt{d}\cos(m!x)^{2d}$ does not exists and thus the function to integrate is undefined.
